# Molecular Gateway white list ~node service

Tags: moleculer

I need to white list all request from ~node service which are help to draw Molecular service UI How can i do this

```
whitelist: ['**'],
```

Answer (score 2):

`$node.*` see in docs actions in [internal service](https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/services.html#Internal-Services)